# How to get access to the model variable in javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I found the same question in stackoverflow forum, but they decided not to help me.

I'm using that code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var testVar = '<%=Model.testProperty %>';
```

Then I paste testVar into alert() method and see only '<%=Model.testProperty %>' as text, but I need access to Model.testProperty value. Help me please

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript